# Button has lower z-index than ImageView even though Button is drawn after it

Tags: android, xml

I'm using [hdodenhof/CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library to use a `CircleImageView`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="@dimen/verticalBias_circle_photo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/credit_score">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle_photo"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
        style="@style/BaseButton"
        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>

<style name="BaseButton">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/button_horizontal_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/button_horizontal_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/button_vertical_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/button_vertical_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/medium_text</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/button_elevation</item>
</style>
```

I understand that in `FrameLayout` the views which are drawn last will be shown on top.

However in my instance, the `Button` is shown *below* the `ImageView`.

Is something off in my code or is this something to do with the library I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

```
        android:elevation="10dp"
```

This is drawing your ImageView over the button. Remove this or add more elevation to the button to show it on top.

Comment: This solved it - I changed it to `android:elevation="0dp"` and it's now workig. Thanks!